# Formatting a value selected from Table C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am creating a data table based on a SQL procedure and then displaying the data table to the frontend like this

```
<b class='dash-main-val'> {info.Rows[rowCountX][columnNames[0]]}</b>
```

Now my problem is that the large numbers get displayed like this
**1234567.33** instead of **1 234 567.33**

How do I format it before displaying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using the [C# number formatting options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) with [String.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1).

```
<b class='dash-main-val'> { String.Format("{0:N}", info.Rows[rowCountX][columnNames[0]])}</b>
```

Comment: I get this error 'No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments' if I make it 
<b class='dash-main-val'> {info.Rows[rowCountX][columnNames[0]].ToString("N")}</b>

Comment: Updated my answer to an alternative approach - give that a go.